# ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget. is raised while run a basic code

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am just learning some styles and designs of kivymd, but for some reason when the code runs
kv = Builder.load_file(MainLayout.kv), it raises the Exception(

**kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.**

).

I just can't get it to run and any further. It has been raising this Exception no matter what changes I make.

And Just for Reference, this is the Code for the Main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivy.core.window import Window


class Login(Screen):
    pass

class Settings(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Login(name='login'))
sm.add_widget(Settings(name='settings'))

sm.current = "login"

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
        pass

    class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
        pass

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Teal"
        Window.size = (412, 732)

        #The Error Occurs when the KV file is loaded
        kv = Builder.load_file("MainLayout.kv")
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

This the Kivy File and in Login File I just have (  )

```
#: include Login.kv
#: include Settings.kv. 
        
NavigationLayout:  
    id:nav_layout

    ScreenManager:
        Screen:  
            BoxLayout:  
                orientation: 'vertical'
                MDToolbar:
                    title: "Kivy Demo App"

                    Widget:
                ScreenManager:
                    id: screen_manager
                    Login:
                        id: login1
                        name: "login"


                    Settings:
                        id: settings1
                        name:"settings"


    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer

        ContentNavigationDrawer:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: "8dp"
            spacing: "8dp"

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Username'

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Captions'
```

Comment: Provide a minimal example. Try deleting as much as possible from this one.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the Advice...Is this enough or should I Delete more? The Main.py is just for reference as I'm new to kivy, I'm not sure if there is a problem over there as well...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was not too hard to fix this. I just Changed the name of the class/page from **settings** to just **setting** and it fixed the problem. Not really sure how it affected the code but would love to know about the bug if anyone might know.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. The class name "Settings" causes the error "ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget". I changed the class name to "Setting" and the screen widget's id and name both to "setting" and everything works fine. Frustrating.